# How do I disable the F1 help in Libreoffce?

Tags: linux, libreoffice

I am using Libreoffice under Linux. I do not want Libreoffice to open up my web browser every time I accidentally press F1. I see nothing about this in their F1 documentation or the man page. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: It seems to me a rather odd feature to have a "Disable F1" option in some software, because F1 is not very common to accidentally hit.

Comment: In libreoffice calc I use F2 constantly to edit cells. That's where I'm having this problem.

Comment: You can install a local version of the help files - not disabling the  `F1`, but you not start up the browser and save bandwidth. HTH (a little)

Comment: Sounds like a decent train of thought. Do you know if I could also change which program opens the help file? Maybe I could change it to a program that terminates immediately.

Comment: @Lombard Did you find a solution? It's really annoying, I want to disable it, but without using the nuclear option documented below.

Comment: @lonix sadly, no, I haven't found a solution other than window manager workarounds that break F1 in general. I discovered that on my system, dbus is telling it to use firefox, but I couldn't figure out how dbus gets that information. dbus is a giant mess. So no good workarounds yet!

Comment: @Lombard I encounter this problem at least once a day! I have a small trick but it's not perfect - get the [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) extension, and use it to trap the "Soffice" app (first run the help, and it'll be named that way in the extension), and move it to a different monitor and make it 1x1 in width/height. It'll steal the focus though, but at least it's out of the way. I was looking for an extension that auto-minimizes or auto-hides a window, but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: [Bad news](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106245). It seems the LibreOffice people can't do anything about it either...

Answer (score 1):

For me too, it is very annoying that it is not possible to disable `F1` in LibreOffice.

In Linux Mint 20.3 it is possible to disable `F1` system wide using onboard GUI.

Start `Keyboard`. On the left select `Custom Shortcuts`. Click `Add custom shortcut`. Enter a name like `disable F1`. Enter a bogus command that will not do anything like `clicked F1`. Select a keyboard binding slot `unassigned` twice and hit `F1`.

In theory it should be possible to create a script using `xdotool` to suppress the key only if 'LibreOffice' is in the name.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems it is generally possible to reassign `F1` button to some non-intrusive function.

On Ubuntu 14.04 where Gnome 3 is the window manager, I've assigned `F1` to `raise` function ("Raise windows above other windows") by using any of the following:

- either [`dconf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dconf) `write` from the command line:

  ```
  dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/raise "['F1']"
  ```
- or using `gsettings set` (also from the command line):

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise "['F1']"
  ```
- or using `dconf-editor` if you prefer a GUI, by navigating to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` and setting `raise` to `['F1']`.

Having done this, hitting `F1` by accident will not do anything because in most usage scenarios your LibreOffice would already be the topmost window.

On a different Linux distribution and/or window manager, I assume a similar solution could be implemented.

Comment: This will make *any* application unable to catch F1 being pressed, not only LibreOffice, right? If so, it should be explicitly stated in the answer.

Comment: This solution could be good if the window manager also has an escape sequence for "no, really, send F1 to the application"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a late answer.... you can always pull "F1" key from your keyboard if this is possible.
But in laptops, it is hard to do it, i think.